# user policies on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, group-policy

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a test server. 
Now I want to try to make user-policies work on that server so that I can control which users can use which software on the server.

Can I do this with openlapd or do I need more or other software. 
And how can I make it work that a user uses software that runs on the server.